# Cython compile error - problems with generator expressions?

Tags: python, generator, cython

I'm trying to cythonise some code I've inherited. It gives an error here:

```
try:
    maxi=xi+next(i for i,z in enumerate(EW[xi:]) if z>=boundingHeight)
except StopIteration: 
    maxi=len(EW)
```

It then prints out a huge stack trace that means nothing to me. It starts with:

```
Compiler crash in AnalyseExpressionsTransform
```

The line itself looks a bit odd to me - I don't quite understand (looks like some kind of generator expression to me) and therefore can happily believe it would be problematic to Cython!!

Edit: Buried in the documentation I found that Cython doesnt support most generator expressions. So I suppose this question becomes: How can rewrite the expression so that it doesn't use a generator?

Comment: This clearly denote a bug in Cython compiler. Which version are you using ? Can you give more co so that the problem can be reproduced ?

Comment: Edited the question - cython wont support generators so now I need to rewrite the expression...

Comment: What version of Cython are you running?  I think that code should work in modern Cython.

Comment: Cython version 0.20.1

Answer (score 1):

We are clearly missing some context, but I believe that the equivalent code should be something like:

```
for i,z in enumerate(EW[xi:]):
    if z>=boundingHeight:
        breaK
else:
    raise StopIteration
maxi=xi+i
```

Comment: Clearly this is not the good way to write things in Cython (the try with `StopIteration` should be rewritten). But without any context I had to stick to this behavior. If you don't manage to fix it by yourself ask another question putting more code and context.